# Determining whether a model with random walk errors is stationary

Tags: time-series, self-study, stochastic-processes, stationarity, autoregressive

If we have a model like an AR(1) except the errors are a random walk (i.e. not iid), then is the model itself stationary? So the model is:
$$
x_t=kx_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
$$
where $k$ is constant and $0<k<1$. As stated, the errors are given by a random walk:
$$
\epsilon_t=\epsilon_{t-1}+\omega_t
$$
where $\omega$ is $\textrm{iid}(\mu=0,\sigma^2)$.

If I've determined the stationary conditions correctly (given $\textrm{Var}(\epsilon_t)=t\sigma^2$), then:
$$
\textrm{Var}(x_t)=\frac{t\sigma^2+2k*\textrm{Cov}(x_{t-1},\epsilon_{t})}{1-k^2}
$$
I am taking this as saying either:

1) the model IS stationary because a finite, non-negative value is given for $\textrm{Var}(x_t)$ or

2) the model is NOT stationary because variance would be changing as $t$ changes.

Could somebody please set me straight?
Thanks!

EDIT: I've made corrections to the stationary conditions for variance. Also, thanks to @Alecos Papadopoulos and @Glen_b who have made me aware that my assumption in 1) is incorrect.

Comment: Why would the condition under (1) be sufficient for stationarity?

Comment: How did you arrive at the expression for the variance of $x_t$?

Answer (score 1):

Going mechanically about it,

$$\text{Var}(x_t)=k^2 \text{Var}[x_{t-1}]+\text{Var}(\epsilon_t) + 2k\text{Cov}(x_{t-1},\epsilon_t)$$

$$= k^2 \text{Var}[x_{t-1}]+t\sigma^2 + 2k(t-1)\sigma^2$$

Set for compactness $\text{Var}(x_t) \equiv z_t$ and $t + 2k(t-1) \equiv h_t$ to get

$$z_t = k^2z_{t-1} + h_t\sigma^2$$

$$\implies z_t = k^4z_{t-2} + k^2h_{t-1}\sigma^2 + h_t\sigma^2$$

$$\implies \text{Var}(x_t) = k^{2t}\text{Var}(x_0) + \sigma^2\cdot [h_t + k^2h_{t-1}+k^4h_{t-2}+...+k^{2(t-1)}h_1]$$

The variance is a function of $t$, and so  the process is not stationary (meaning second-order stationary, since it is first-order stationary -stationary in the mean).
Just being finite for finite value of the index was never a criterion for second-order stationarity.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try to give an additional answer.
$$
\textrm{Var}(x_t)=k^2\textrm{Var}(x_{t-1})+t\sigma^2+2k*\textrm{Cov}(x_{t-1},\epsilon_t)
$$
If $\textrm{Var}(x_t)=\textrm{Var}(x_{t-1})$ then:
$$
\textrm{Var}(x_t)=k^2\textrm{Var}(x_{t})+t\sigma^2+2k*\textrm{Cov}(x_{t-1},\epsilon_t)
$$
$$
\textrm{Var}(x_t)=k^2\textrm{Var}(x_{t})+t\sigma^2+2k(t-1)\sigma^2
$$
$$
\textrm{Var}(x_t)=\frac{t\sigma^2+2k(t-1)\sigma^2}{1-k^2}\neq\frac{(t-1)\sigma^2+2k((t-1)-1)\sigma^2}{1-k^2}
$$
So because the variance is dependent on $t$, $\textrm{Var}(x_t)\neq\textrm{Var}(x_{t-1})$ and the model is not stationary. Does this seem OK?